# Assign the number of rows with text to a variable

Tags: vba, excel

First let me start by saying i am fairly new to programming, especially to Excel VBA. I am writing a long code to help me optimize some of my daily tasks. For now there is one thing i cannot figure out yet, so i will paste only this part of the code.

I want to count the number of active rows(such which have text in them) in the target sheet i am using and assign that number to a variable (integer).

Can you please explain to me how to do that?

Here is the code i thought it would work:

```
targetSheet.Range("A2").Select   
targetSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select    
Selection.Count

Dim count As Integer

count = Selection.Count
```

obviously it doesn't work and i cannot refer to 'count' in the continuation of the code (it gives me an error)

i would be very thankful if you could help me with that!

Regards,
Mihail

Comment: I apologize in the subject it should say 'Active cells'!

Comment: you can always edit your question which is welcome

Comment: I guess, you have "Overflow error". Selection.Count actually returns Long, but you assign it to Integer. When Count is less that Integer can hold, code will work, but when it's greater than Integer, you'll get "Overflow" error.

Comment: Using xlDown to find the last row fails whenever column A contains empty cells in between filled cells. (So in some situations you might need to use UsedRange and xlUp to find the last row). You know your data best, so you can decide whether xlDown works in this case ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Dim CellsCount As Long

With targetSheet
    .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Select ' <-- if you must use Select

    CellsCount = Selection.Count
End With
```

However, you don't need to `Select` the range to count the number of cells:

```
With targetSheet
    CellsCount = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
End With
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it does not help me when i want to use the number later in the code. When i try to refer the CellsCount it gives me an Application defined or Object defined error

Comment: @M_Delineshev  did you had the line that defines this variable ?